# how do i interface xml file to my method

Tags: android

I have one method which is handling the data to be displayed in the expandable list and listview or i may say the parent item and the child item.

here is the prepareListData method:

```
private void prepareListData() {

    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    // Adding child data
    listDataHeader.add("VRP Medical Bay");
    //listDataHeader.add("");
    //listDataHeader.add("");

    // Adding child data
    List<String> listUnderVRP = new ArrayList<String>();
    //this is the data that i need to get from my xml service
            listUnderVRP.add("eDataClinical");
    listUnderVRP.add("Schedule");
    listUnderVRP.add("Dictate");
    listUnderVRP.add("View Messages");
    listUnderVRP.add("Reports for Signature");
    listUnderVRP.add("View Billing");
    listUnderVRP.add("View State");


    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), listUnderVRP); // Header, Child data
    //listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), listUnderVRP1);
    //listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), listUnderVRP2);
}
```

My question is, how do i integrate an xml file to this method, because i want to get the datas from an xml file so that i can customized my listview.

i want to implement this code:

```
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);
    // looping through all song nodes <song>
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
        map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
        map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        songsList.add(map);
    }
```

Comment: you will have to implement an xml parser.

Comment: hi @DanielBo, do you have any idea how to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

The implementation Depends on your XML file. But this should get you started.

```
    try {
        System.setProperty("org.xml.sax.driver","org.xmlpull.v1.sax2.Driver");
        createXMLReader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
        createXMLReader.setContentHandler(new DefaultHandler() {

            Lesson currentLesson;

            @Override
            public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
                if ("attributeName".equals(localName)){
                    String value = attributes.getValue("attributeValue");

                }
            }
        });
        createXMLReader.parse(new InputSource(activity.getResources().getAssets().open("yourXML")));
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```